# facebook's chat head react native

Tags: facebook, react-native, widget, floating

I'm having trouble creating facebook-like chat heads. I am using the react-native-floating-bubble library. When I call the showFloatingBubble () function, it falls into catch and the chat head is not displayed. Could someone help me solve this problem?
Library Link -> https://github.com/hybriteq/react-native-floating-bubble/blob/master/README.md

## App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import {
  showFloatingBubble,
  hideFloatingBubble,
  requestPermission,
  checkPermission,
  initialize,
} from 'react-native-floating-bubble';

class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    showFloatingBubble();

    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
      const fcmToken = firebase.messaging().getToken();
      console.log('fcmToken', fcmToken);
      firebase.notifications().onNotification(notification => {
        alert(notification);
      });
    } else {
      try {
        firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
      } catch (e) {
        alert('usuário rejeitou as permissões');
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <></>;
  }
}
export default App;
```

## MainApplication.java

```
    package com.poc;

    import android.app.Application;
    import android.content.Context;
    import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
    import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
    import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;
    import com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.ReactNativePushNotificationPackage;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
    import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
    import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

      private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
          new ReactNativeHost(this) {
            @Override
            public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
              return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
            }


            @Override
            protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
              @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
              List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
              packages.add(new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage());
              packages.add(new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage());

              return packages;
            };

            @Override
            protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
              return "index";
            }
          };

      @Override
      public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled
      }

      /**
       * Loads Flipper in React Native templates.
       *
       * @param context
       */
      private static void initializeFlipper(Context context) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
          try {
            /*
             We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
            since Flipper library is not available in release mode
            */
            Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper");
            aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class).invoke(null, context);
          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

## build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false)

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.poc"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-floating-bubble')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/"
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

## settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'poc'
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-push-notification'
project(':react-native-push-notification').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android')
include ':react-native-floating-bubble'
project(':react-native-floating-bubble').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-floating-bubble/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
```